# Can Convolutional Neural Networks (CNNs) be accurately represented as directed acyclic graphs (DAGs)?

Tags: neural-networks, interpretation, conv-neural-network, graph-theory

While it's evident that fully connected layers, even with skip connections, form DAGs, the shared weights in convolutional layers introduce complexity. How does the unique structure of convolutional layers affect their representation as DAGs?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! I've seen discussions about the relationship between CNNs and graph neural networks (GNNs, not to be confused with GAN generative adversarial networks), where CNNs are a special case of GNNs, so I have to think the answer is an emphatic YES. I would be quite interested in an answer that expands upon this. Perhaps this comment can point you in a direction to be able to write a self-answer about the connection. (Self-answers are allowed on here, perhaps encouraged, rather than being seen as arrogant, know-it-all, or showing off.)

Comment: It is the sharing of weights that stumps me. I don't think I have seen graphs where the same edge connects multiple pairs of nodes. Does this narrow down my difficulty in seeing CNNs as DAGs?